# Xcode other swift flags vs Active Compilation Confitions vs other for preprocessor

Tags: xcode, preprocessor

I want to add new directive, for example `SUNNY`. In order that I can write `#if SUNNY ... #endif`.

**What** should I use in Build Settings, **why** and in **which format**?

- Other swift flags
- Active compilation conditions
- Preprocessor macros

Now I think that answer is:

Other swift flags - `-DSUNNY`
Active compilation conditions - `SUNNY` + `$(inherited)`
Preprocessor macros - `SUNNY=1`

,but not sure and don't exactly know why.